# Issue with making chart dynamic, using formula name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, bar-chart

I wanted to make my bar chart dynamic. For this purpose I have used `=A1:INDEX(A2:A60;COUNTA(A2:A60))` formula. I gave a name to this formula using name manager. When I use this formula in my X-AXIS LABEL RANGE (in bar chart -> select data), I am getting error **The formula you typed contain an error**. But my formula is working well in cell.

Please suggest, where I am doing it wrong. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter a named range into a chart series dialog or the label dialog, you must precede the range name with either the sheet name or the file name.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

See how the formula for the x axis labels is entered as `=Sheet1!chtLabels`

The formula for the range name is

`=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$60,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$60))`

Similar for the series definitions. The range name alone is not sufficient. It has to be preceded by the sheet name (or the file name).

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works. But my chart values in not updating after 14. am I using right formula to make chart dynamic. Also there is little typo in =Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$60,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$60)) . it need semicolon before COUNTA.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion is very useful. Offset function is more reliable than index function. for my case.

Comment: That comma/semicolon is not a typo. Your regional settings use the semicolon as the list separator, so that is what Excel wants in formulas to separate parameters. Most other regional settings use the comma instead, so when I post a formula or a screenshot, it will have the comma.

Comment: sorry and  thanks for info, i dint know this. Now got this why  many examples have comma as separator :)